# Dict with multiple values per key sorted by one of the values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictonary of keys, each with nested values with keys/labels. Ik it's a bad explanation, see example below.

```
{
'ATVI': 
    {'momentum': 1695172800449.7812, 'sma': 81.97039999999998}, 
'ADBE': 
    {'momentum': 15.37463410207528, 'sma': 484.3043000000006}, 
'AMD': 
    {'momentum': 7.319987019427009e+20, 'sma': 85.5414}
}
```

I need to generate a list of the 20 keys which have the highest momentums. What is the best way to do this without affecting the information in this dictionary.

Comment: can you add the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method would be to store a list of the top level keys sorted by momentum.

```
data = {'ATVI': {'momentum': 1695172800449.7812, 'sma': 81.97039999999998}, 'ADBE': {'momentum': 15.37463410207528, 'sma': 484.3043000000006}, 'AMD': {'momentum': 7.319987019427009e+20, 'sma': 85.5414}}

sdata = list(data.keys())
sdata.sort(key=lambda x: data[x]["momentum"])
```

From here you would have to access the dictionary as you iterate through the list. If you wanted the list to be decreasing you can set `reverse=True` after `key`

Edit: To get the top 20 you could slice the list by `sdata[-20:]` or if you used reverse `sdata[:20]`. As mentioned there may be an issue of the 20th and 21st element having the same value.

Comment: If you did not want to keep a seperate list of the keys in order you could utilize collections.OrderedDict and after sorting the list of keys iterate through the list inserting into the OrderedDict. This would preserve the ordering and give you dictionary functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the momentums into a separate dict:

`momentums = {k: v['momentum'] for k, v in d.items()}`

Then get the keys for the top 20 highest values with:

`[k for k, v in momentums.items() if v in sorted(momentums.values())[-20:]]`

(There could be edge cases where the 20th and 21st highest momentums are exactly the same in which case this will arbitrarily choose one of the keys; so it depends on how careful you need to be as to whether you need something more sophisticated.)